# I'm getting this error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: mysql-error-1064

> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

This is the code:

```
/* execute SQL INSERT command */
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO form 
    (datesubmit,uitmid, idnumber, roomnumber, collegename, studname, phone, part,
    program, faculty, cgpa, position1, position2, email, vehicle, 
    advisorname, hpnumberadvisor, emailadvisor, academic, oku,
    date, sex, religion, address, fathername, fatherhp,
    salfather, mothername, motherhp, salmother, namesibling1, ipt1, namesibling2,
    ipt2, namesibling3, ipt3, namesibling4, ipt4, namesibling5, ipt5, namesibling6, ipt6, namesibling7, ipt7,
    namesibling8, ipt8, namesibling9, ipt9, namesibling10, ipt10)
    VALUES (now(),'" . $uitmid . "', '" . $idnumber . "', '" . $roomnumber . "', '" . $collegename . "',
    '" . $studname . "', '" . $phone . "', '" . $part . "', '" . $program . "', '" . $faculty . "',
    '" . $cgpa . "', '" . $position1 . "', '" . $position2 . "', '" . $email . "', '" . $vehicle . "',
    '" . $advisorname . "', '" . $hpnumberadvisor . "', '" . $emailadvisor . "', '" . $academic . "', '" . $oku . "',
    '" . $date . "', '" . $sex . "',
    '" . $religion . "', '" . $address . "', '" . $fathername . "', '" . $fatherhp . "', '" . $salfather . "', '" . $mothername . "',
    '" . $motherhp . "', '" . $salmother . "', '" . $namesibling1 . "', '" . $ipt1 . "',
    '" . $namesibling2 . "', '" . $ipt2 . "', '" . $namesibling3 . "', '" . $ipt3 . "',
    '" . $namesibling4 . "', '" . $ipt4 . "', '" . $namesibling5 . "','" . $ipt5 . "' ,'" . $namesibling6 . "' ,'" . $ipt6 . "', 
    '" . $namesibling7 . "' ,'" . $ipt7 . "' ,'" . $namesibling8 . "' ,'" . $namesibling9 . "' ,'" . $ipt9 . "' ,'" . $namesibling10 . "' ,'" . $ipt10 . "')";
    mysql_query($sql2) or die ("Error: " . mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

The query is missing a values for ipt8. The error occurred because the values being inserted didn't match the number of fields specified in the table.